# Order of nameservers on client given by DHCP

Tags: networking, server, 17.10, dns, dhcp

I'm running DNS and DHCP server on debian 8 server within local network.
Issue is that clients get nameservers by DHCP server in wrong/not desired order.

DHCP server config:

```
subnet 192.168.10.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {  
option routers 192.168.10.1;  
option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;  
option domain-name-servers 192.168.10.1, 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4;  
option time-offset -18000;    
default-lease-time 21600;  
max-lease-time 43200;  
}
```

Where 192.168.10.1 is DNS and DHCP server.

Nameservers listed for local interface on client:

```
IP4.DNS[1]:                             8.8.8.8  
IP4.DNS[2]:                             8.8.4.4  
IP4.DNS[3]:                             192.168.10.1
```

Client is Ubuntu 17.10

**How to get nameservers in proper order from DHCP server?**
*Desired order is to have local name server used first.

Ergo:*

```
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.10.1   
IP4.DNS[2]:                             8.8.8.8  
IP4.DNS[3]:                             8.8.4.4
```